# How can I allow a user to grant a SaaS app in Azure access to display their network info

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Im developing a SaaS app to run on Azure that allows users to view information about their network configuration, for instance VNET information. Ive added user_impersonation permissions to the API. But when users initially authenticate with the app, and they accept the permission request modal displaying "Access Azure Service Management as you (preview)" unless I manually give that user "contributor" role access, they cannot access the API. Is there no way for this to be streamlined so any user who grants the app permissions, can view this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the delegated permission below to the app,  the user who logged in to the app must have the permission to the azure resources(i.e. have the RBAC role in the subscription/specific resource scope).

When the user consents the delegated permission, the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to an API. The permission is from the user, not the app itself. So in your case, you need to give the users the RBAC roles(e.g. the `Contributor` role you mentioned).

For more details about delegated permission, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types).

If you can accept that the user who logged in to the app can access the azure resources, give the service principal of the app as an RBAC role, the app itself will be able to access the azure resource, then you can use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token and use it to access the resources.

[image]

Comment: So suppose this app is a SaaS app available on the marketplace. A user subscribes to the app, they would then need to have their role updated with the contributor role? Is that something that would be part of the subscription flow?

Comment: @Brian The role needs to be assigned by the `owner/user access admin` of the subscription/resource, actually it is reasonable, if the user himself has the permission, then the app can represent him to access the resource. If not, then the app also can't.

Comment: Joy I see. So you're saying this is a standard procedure for any user who would want to subscribe to an app like this? They would manually give themselves the "contributor" role and continue to go about using the app? (this is my first time using azure)

Comment: @Brian Yes, you are right. Otherwise, all the users login the app can consent the permission, they will be able to access the azure resources.I think this is not what the subscription owner wants to see.;-)